# cómo hago para que la altura de un <section> sea la misma que la del viewport?

Tags: html, height, viewport

Necesito que la altura de un elemento `<section>` sea la misma que la del **"viewport"**.

Answer (score 0):

La solución era poner `height: 100vh;`.